# Matrix multiplication R

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I just have an easy question: I have these two matrices

Matrix Y (264 rows and 4 columns)

```
      [,1]      [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
1751 -1.745529 0.3692280 0.04607022 -0.07004973
1752 -1.532722 0.5642921 0.07477571  0.03380135  
1753 -1.657636 0.4660229 0.05772685 -0.03314599
1754 -1.685309 0.4540047 0.08254891 -0.01623810
1755 -1.702469 0.4483389 0.10709689 -0.03936556
1756 -1.761332 0.4505378 0.04801420 -0.06385137
```

Matrix E (4x4,of elements e)

```
       [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
[1,] -0.8769976 -0.4706054 -0.07186508  0.06512449
[2,] -0.4085563  0.8198519 -0.40067903 -0.01951755
[3,]  0.2190770 -0.3206892 -0.86394973 -0.32055350
[4,] -0.1263415  0.0594299  0.29644997 -0.94478745
```

I want to do this for each year b(t)=∑(e[1,i]∙Y[,i]) with i from 1 to 4.

This is what I should get (a matrix 264x4),and this is the code I've used

```
betaNew1<-(Y[,1]%*%t(P[1,1]))
betaNew2<-(Y[,2]%*%t(P[1,2]))
betaNew3<-(Y[,3]%*%t(P[1,3]))
betaNew4<-(Y[,3]%*%t(P[1,4]))
beta_t<-data.frame(betaNew1,betaNew2,betaNew3,betaNew4)

   betaNew1   betaNew2     betaNew3    betaNew4
1 1.530825 -0.1737607 -0.003310840  0.003000300
2 1.344193 -0.2655589 -0.005373763  0.004869730
3 1.453743 -0.2193129 -0.004148544  0.003759431
4 1.478012 -0.2136570 -0.005932384  0.005375955
5 1.493062 -0.2109907 -0.007696526  0.006974630
6 1.544684 -0.2120255 -0.003450544  0.003126900
```

How can I avoid to use 4 instructions?

Comment: start [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matmult.html)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I know how to use the matrix product but I'm trying to do something different, like this:  Y[,1]%*%t(P[1,1]). I don't want to repeat this instruction four times: Y[,1]%*%t(P[1,1]),Y[,2]%*%t(P[1,2]),Y[,3]%*%t(P[1,3]),Y[,4]%*%t(P[1,4])

Comment: @akrun: I've edited it. I think it's different from the other question

Comment: Are these values in the expected output correct?

Comment: No,only the first column is correct. In the other columns I put random values just to show how it should be. I'm trying to use a for-loop betaNew<-matrix(data=NA,nrow=264,ncol=4)
for(i in 1:4)
 betaNew[i] <- matrix((Y[,i]%*%t(P[1,i]))), but I get this error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Comment: I am getting different numbers for the first column (using the first 6 rows of "Y" with `lapply(seq_len(ncol(P)), function(i) do.call(cbind,lapply(1:nrow(P), function(j) Y[,i] %*%t(P[j,i]))))`

Comment: I've re-edited my question...probably it's my fault, as I'm not able to explain decently

Comment: The above code also gives the same result, but in this case I have loop through all the rows, so will get the entire output

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
res <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(P)), function(i) Y*P[i,][col(Y)])
```